# Rails 4 asset pipeline Heroku production javascript reference issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been trying to figure out an asset pipeline issue I've been having. I'm using raphael.js for a project and and for some reason it's saying it can't find the reference to it. This only happens when rails_env is production. If I use chromes developer tool bar I can see the generated js file and can see the raphael.js class defined in it. The references to it are defined further down in the same generated asset file but for some reason it can't find the reference. Has anybody ran into this before? If I use RAILS_ENV=development everything works fine. It doesn't appear to be a missing asset since I can see the class in the file. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My issue ended up being a combination of smaller app specific issues. After reviewing the rails guide again for the asset pipeline and additional debugging I was able to resolve the issues.